# Rounding time to nearest quarter, atleast 30 minutes in time

Tags: php

Bah, I've been fiddling on how to do this. I need a function that returns `<hour>:<minutes>` that is rounded to a quarter, but need to be atleast 30 minutes in future time.

Anyone got a good idea and how to do this?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Can you get the rounding part to work but not the 30 mins in the future part? Or vice versa? Or both?

Comment: Can you give an example of the time entered and what converted value you expect?

Comment: What is the input for the function? Please be more specific with your question. At least give an example (data you give to the function => data you want to be produced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add 30 minutes.
2. Extract date + hour on the one hand side, minutes on the other.
3. Divide minutes by 15, ceil the result, multiply by 15.
4. Build new date using date + hour and add the new minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$current = date("Hi");
$ceilUp = ceil($current / 15);
$timeNeeded = $ceilUp + 30;
```

something like that? (I see it's not exactly what you need.. but this is a start).